# React.js Route problem from react-route-dom

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hello everyone I am new to react.js. my problem is when I use Route in `react-router-dom` it doesn't work as I wanted to

So, I have a link like *[www.div.example.com/test/test-1](http://www.div.example.com/test/test-1)* as the home page and I have Route

```
Import React from "react";
Import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
Import User from "./User"

const App = () => {



  return (
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path = "/user" exact component ={User}/> 
    </Switch>
</Router>
}

export default App
```

The **User Component**   :

```
Import React from "react";

const User = () => {



  return (
<div> User </div>
}

export default User
```

And I have a Link that should make the link work according to the previous url like

*[www.div.example.com/test/test-1/user](http://www.div.example.com/test/test-1/user)*

My Link code

`<Link to = "./user" />`

The thing is **Link** is **working**

But the **Route Component** won't show up

My homepage in `package.json` is

`"homepage" : "."`

I searched so much but no clue

Can you help?

Comment: Did you try add `exact` prop into `<Route ... exact />`?

Comment: Yes i did but nothing the component won't show up

Comment: Can you post all of your code? I don't see a component being passed to the route

Comment: Ok i added the source code and User component Source code

Comment: try this in your app.js file export default () => ( <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path = "/user" exact component ={User}/> 
    </Switch>
</Router>);

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
<Link to = "./user" />
```

you need

```
<Link to="/user" />
```

Comment: When i do  that the url become  www.div.example.com/user

Comment: Is the user component rendered in this case?

Comment: If your app is served from a sub-directory on your server, you need to add a basename to your BrowserRouter. Using the code below, all routes will have a test as the basename.

`<Router basename="/test">
    <Switch>
      <Route path = "/user" exact component ={User}/> 
    </Switch>
</Router>
`

Comment: Now that somthing new i will try it and give you updates

Comment: About the user component rendered no it doesn't

Comment: Update it's worked. Now is there any way that i won't add the basename and git the URL automatic instead of adding  ```basename = "/test"``` I want the value to be automated?

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to create route, which will be based on the previous route. If yes, only way is to create ton of routes (with all options of previous route), which will render the same component.
For example your app has 3 routes (/first_test,  /second_test, /third_test). You will need to create 3 routes <Route path = "/first_test/user" exact component ={User}/> , <Route path = "/second_test/user" exact component ={User}/>, ...

Comment: But from the architectural side it's absolutely inflexible to create routes, which will be based on the previous route. Usually creates just one /user route.